# Get information from dll

Tags: c, dll, mex

I have a mexfile that i succed to have it dll file to use it in a c++ program. The problem that i dont have any information about the name and parameter of functions in the dll file. I try to use dependance walker program to get information about dll file. the program give this:

Function Name   Address     Relative Address    Ordinal

```
mexFunction 0x10004fc0  0x00004fc0          1 (0x1)
```

The problem is that i'm sure that the `dll` file has many function not only one, i dont know how to do to call this functions and have their parameter.

Any help please.

Comment: Without a documented prototype you're going to be spending time on the business-end of a debugger, and unless your a glutton for punishment, a disassembler. and after all that if you're *lucky* you will be able to call it correctly. You could save yourself a lot of time by debugging an application that *correctly* invokes this, btw.

Comment: I have a matlab code that use this dll but i dont know how to debugg that?

Comment: If matlab code uses Dll, it should contain function prototypes. You don't need to debug, just find the right place in matlab code.

Comment: You call MEX files from _MATLAB_, not from C++.